# KML title and description to generate lettered legend on map

Tags: google-maps, kml, legend

Let's say I've exported a KML (from My Google Maps) with a list of waypoints like:

```
  <Placemark>
    <name>Bachledzki Wierch 8a</name>
    <description>tel: , 606 426 336</description>
    <styleUrl>#icon-1602-DB4436</styleUrl>
    <Point>
      <coordinates>
        19.9706636999999,49.3048297,0
      </coordinates>
    </Point>
  </Placemark>
```

Seemed simple, yet I was unable to find an online tool to auto-populate a legend with labels A, B, C, etc. using those points.

Any suggestions?

I went so far as to assign custom raster images to the icons of each Placemark, to attain alphabet letters.

[image: screenshot001]

However, no print, export nor even screenshot configurable in https://www.google.com/maps/d manages to show the `<description>` field also *in the legend*, only the `<name>` field alone (without the vital contact info I need to print out).

Is there any tool that dynamically generates the legend table, showing both name/title *and* description for each placemark, automatically lettering them, and ideally using the KML feed or My Google Map URL to stay updated? (Although I can manually export a new KMZ/KML after every change, if I must.)

Comment: Loosely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55124600/adding-a-dynamic-legend-based-off-of-kml-file-contents-within-google-earth